# explode() is not working as expected in python with spark for nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pyspark, explode

My nested JSON is like below.

```
{
"dc_id": "dc-101",
"source": {
    "sensor-igauge": {
      "id": 10,
      "ip": "68.28.91.22",
      "description": "Sensor attached to the container ceilings",
      "temp":35,
      "c02_level": 1475,
      "geo": {"lat":38.00, "long":97.00}                        
    },
    "sensor-ipad": {
      "id": 13,
      "ip": "67.185.72.1",
      "description": "Sensor ipad attached to carbon cylinders",
      "temp": 34,
      "c02_level": 1370,
      "geo": {"lat":47.41, "long":-122.00}
    }}}
```

I also have a schema for the above data.

```
schema = StructType([
  StructField("dc_id", StringType(),True),                              
  StructField("source",MapType(StringType(),StructType([
    StructField("description",StringType(),True),
    StructField("ip",StringType(),True),
    StructField("id",StringType(),True),
    StructField("temp",StringType(),True),
    StructField("c02_level",StringType(),True),
    StructField("geo",StructType([
      StructField("lat",DoubleType(),True),
      StructField("long",DoubleType(),True),
    ]),True)
  ])),True)])
```

I want to know, how to use this schema in python to show data.
I was made a code like this.

```
dataDS = (scSpark.createDataFrame(
            [({
"dc_id": "dc-101",
"source": {
    "sensor-igauge": {
      "id": 10,
      "ip": "68.28.91.22",
      "description": "Sensor attached to the container ceilings",
      "temp":35,
      "c02_level": 1475,
      "geo": {"lat":38.00, "long":97.00}                        
    },
    "sensor-ipad": {
      "id": 13,
      "ip": "67.185.72.1",
      "description": "Sensor ipad attached to carbon cylinders",
      "temp": 34,
      "c02_level": 1370,
      "geo": {"lat":47.41, "long":-122.00}
    }}})]))

dataDS.select("dc_id","source",explode(format("source")).alias("sensor_name","sensor_value"))\
.select("dc_id","source","sensor_name","sensor_value",explode("sensor_value")).show()
```

Please note that in place of format() i was used parse() before but got **NameError: name 'parser' is not defined**. I was also tried to run this using **from parser import *** but getting same error.

The result is something like this which is not as expected.
[image: Please check the result output]

ip,description and geo come as null.

Any idea how can i handle this in pyspark or using python, i want all values with nested values for geo key.
String type and Struct type data are not coming.